# MPI derived datatype .Send rows of an array of structs with MPI (C)

Tags: arrays, struct, parallel-processing, mpi, derived-types

I got an MPI programm that uses MPI derived datatype.
I got a struct :

```
typedef struct Cars {
float x;
float y;
float z;
float maxDist;
int type; //Nq or Nc
int bx;
int by;
int bz;
int process;
} car;
```

And create MPI datatype:

```
   MPI_Type_create_struct(items,blocklengths,offsets,car,&car_type);


   MPI_Datatype   types[9]={ MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_INT,
   MPI_INT,MPI_INT,MPI_INT,MPI_INT};
   MPI_Datatype   mpi_point_type;
   MPI_Aint       offsets[9];

   offsets[0]=offsetof(point,x);
   offsets[1]=offsetof(point,y);
   offsets[2]=offsetof(point,z);
   offsets[3]=offsetof(point,maxDist);
   offsets[4]=offsetof(point,type);
   offsets[5]=offsetof(point,bx);
   offsets[6]=offsetof(point,by);
   offsets[7]=offsetof(point,bz);
   offsets[8]=offsetof(point,process);
              MPI_Type_create_struct(items,blocklengths,offsets,types,&mpi_point_type);


     MPI_Type_commit(&car_type);


     MPI_Datatype rowtype;
     MPI_Type_contiguous(column,car_type,&rowtype);
     MPI_Type_commit(&rowtype);


                MPI_Type_create_struct(items,blocklengths,offsets,types,&car_type);
     MPI_Type_commit(&car_type);
```

I have arrays of type

```
   car *recvBuf=malloc(sizeof *recvBuf *(column+4));  
   car *forSent=malloc(sizeof *forSent * row * column); // 2d array                              //stored in 1d (points sent between processes)



  for(j=0;j<numTasks;j++){

  if(j!=rank){
   MPI_Isend(&forSent[j*column],1,rowtype,j,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req[2]);
```

`[j*column]` refers to the j-th process that should point address that is be sending. Each row refers to a different process
For example :1st process sends to 2nd process point `&forSent[1*column]`

```
             MPI_Irecv(recvBuf,1,rowtype,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req[3]);  

   if(rank==0){
   for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
   printf("RECEIVED %d \n",recvBuf[i].bz);}
   }
   }

  }
  }
```

Where "bz" is a member of car type structs,which is initialized in program's function , and it's tested that initialized with the right way.
But in Receive part i got rubbish.When i do same stuff with MPI_INT arguements instead of (car_type) my results are good.
Is there an error in nested type use in sending? 
Whats going on?

Comment: What language is that supposed to be. Please provide a more complete example of what you have already tried.

Comment: So you do have code but it doesn't work? if so please show the code in form of a [mcve] as well as the expected and actual result (*how is it wrong?*) The snippets you posted don't make any sense. What is `mpi_point_type`? Why not created the `MPI_Type_contiguous` on top of `car_type`? BTW: You don't even need to create an extra contiguous type, you can just send `column` elements of `car_type`.

Comment: @Zulan i tried to fix this.I am stack on this problem for two weeks or something and i am desperate.My whole program is about 500 lines so it cant be upload

Comment: If it works with integers but not with the Car type then my guess would be that your call to MPI_Type_create_struct() is incorrect. If you could give a complete piece of code for that part (i.e. specifying how you compute the arguments) then we could at least debug that part.

Comment: @DavidHenty I added code that you request

Comment: If you're truly stuck on this, and you have work you're trying to do with the code that's more consequential, just work around it: allocate a flat array of `ints` or `floats` or whatever, pack the relevant values into it and pass that as the argument to `MPI_Isend` and the corresponding receive, and then unpack into the real structure on the other end.

Comment: You mean do it with MPI_Pack? I am stack with this ,and cant understand how it cant work. It Receives rubbish , or Zeros ( 0 ) when i am printing the recv buffer.I think that thing i do with MPI_Isend is the simplest.I have a 1d array .

Comment: This code is very confusing. You create the car_type with undefined values, then create a point_type with the correct parameters but never use it, ... I would suggest a) remove the first call to create_struct b) replace point_type with car_type in the 2nd create_struct; c) delete the last two calls to create_struct and commit.